# Delete Duplicate records and keep one in MYSQL version 5.7 ( Table with out primary key)

Tags: mysql, duplicates

We have some duplicate entries in our Items Table and trying to delete them but need one out of them

Table: Items (No Primary Key

```
ItemNumber,lastModifiedDate
10056,'2020-10-19'
10056,'2020-10-19'
10057,'2020-10-19'
10057,'2020-10-20'
```

Expected Output:

```
ItemNumber,lastModifiedDate
10056,'2020-10-19'
10057,'2020-10-20'
```

I tried below :

```
delete from Items where (ItemNumber,LastModifiedDate) not in
(
SELECT
ItemNumber,max(LastModifiedDate) LastModifiedDate
FROM
(select * from Items ) Items
GROUP BY
ItemNumber
);
```

We can do it in Mysql V8 using ROW_NUMBER() windows Function, but that feature is not available in 5.7, and i can't upgrade the DB now.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually tricky because your duplicate records are really identical in every way.  One approach here is to filter off the duplicates in a temporary table.  Then truncate your current table and populate it using the filtered data.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ItemsTemp AS (
    SELECT ItemNumber, MAX(lastModifiedDate) AS lastModifiedDate
    FROM Items
    GROUP BY ItemNumber
)

TRUNCATE TABLE Items;  -- remove all data in Items

-- repopulate Items using non duplicate data
INSERT INTO Items (ItemNumber, lastModifiedDate)
SELECT ItemNumber, lastModifiedDate
FROM ItemsTemp;

DROP TABLE ItemsTemp;  -- drop the temporary table
```

Comment: OP needs to save one copy of `MAX(lastModifiedDate)` for each `ItemNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in other way round.

alter table add id column with auto increment by 1,
then you got the differentiator, group by the required fields, keep min(id) record and delete remaining duplicates.